# What is the best way to make versioned files available for download

Tags: version-control

I have a small PHP framework which I want to make available for download. It is located in a git repository. But the last version is not always the one that I want to make available for download. Is there some place I can make the versions available for download.

Another thing about this framework is that I bring out additional components for the framework. These also have different versions.

Is there somewhere where I can add the whole project, and people can browse trough everything and download what they need.

Or should I make this myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is opensource you could try [Google Project Hosting](http://code.google.com/projecthosting/) or [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/register/)

Comment: sourceforge is just what I am looking for. I can create my own filestructure here. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use [tagging](http://learn.github.com/p/tagging.html). It is a way to make note of a "snapshot" of your repository at a particular time (or, rather, at a particular commit) in its history.

Also, look at [git-archive](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html). The command exports the content of your repository at any particular commit (e.g., using tag!) into an archive (unversioned).

Comment: Yes tagging would be nice, but I also develop libaries and helpers seperate from the source. It would be a little bit confusing for me. But I will look into tagging. Thank you +1

Comment: In that case, look into [git-submodule](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html). I haven't played with it extensively myself, but it does store the particular commit IDs of your submodules at a given commit (of the super-module).

Answer (score 1):

Just put it on github.com and use tags to mark particular states and may be usable states of your development.